# Natively install Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, 18.04

#### Questions:

Is there an Ubuntu 18.04 which is bundled with Unity instead of Gnome3?

#### Description:

I liked the Gnome look and feel for a desktop computer with a large screen but for a laptop I definitely prefer Unity which saves a lot of space (I tried without success to get the windows controls at the left of the menu bar for any application on Gnome without success and after having tried many extensions like 'no-tittle-bar' or 'unite').

This page (along with others) is pretty straightforward to install Unity once Ubuntu 18.04 is set up: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-unity-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

But is there a pre-bundle Ubuntu 18.04 iso image which comes with Unity instead of Gnome3?

I feel it would be a mess to:
  1) install Unity and
  2) remove Gnome3 (and all of its dependencies without affecting applications behaviour on Unity). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently (Dec 2018) **NO** Unity bundle: Unity is not a fully-fledged flavor of Ubuntu. It's a community-supported Desktop Environment, which is only one element of an Ubuntu Flavor. Creating the .iso files for download is another element.

Many flavors of Ubuntu started this way, slowly growing and gathering members until they could support their new flavor properly. You can join the Unity effort, contributing patches, documentation, and testing, at http://discourse.ubuntu.com.

A common method of installing Unity that you may find more appealing is to start with the [Minimal Installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), then install the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage.

Answer (score 0):

You could try customizing the Ubuntu ISO yourself.

Use these instructions as a guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Once you're in the chroot environment, try following these instructions to switch from Gnome to Unity: https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/